# Set default storage to SD card on Moto E running Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sd-card, motorola-moto-e

I have Moto E 2nd gen. and I want to set SD card as my default storage. I googled but nothing useful found. Can someone help me?

Comment: could you tell us for what purpose? for download storage?

Comment: @LinX64 yes for download storage.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways for doing this:

- See this [video](https://youtu.be/uDwl7X2OEzE) on YouTube, if your phone can support this method; Or,
- See this [video](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1772970/set-default-download-location-card.html) to use default file manager to change the storage; Or,
- Use file managers like [**ES File Explorer File Manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). When you try to download a file, it shows you the pop up menu and then you can choose the path for storing the files; Or,
- Use Google Chrome Browser. In Chrome, tap the tools drop-down bar in the top right corner → tap **Settings** → tap **Show advanced settings**, and enter the file path you want where the file should download.

  In other browsers the process is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way:

1. Open the Camera app.
2. Swipe on the middle of the screen from the left to the right. This may take a couple of tries so be persistent.
3. This gives a half-moon shaped menu on the left.  Slide this menu counter clockwise to the icon of an sd card.  Tap on this.
4. Choose Phone or SD card for the storage location.